# How to replace single digit zero '0' (one digit only) with a string value in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I want to replace zero **'0'** with a string value **N/A**. I already used a replace function but the problem with replace function is that it replaces 0 with a String at every occurrence in digit value **(e.g 20 to 2N/A)**. I want to replace a string with the **single-digit** value '0'.

I am using the current query with replace function as below:

```
select left(pdc.semester,6) as Sem1,RIGHT(pdc.semester,4) as sem2,pdc.semester as Semester,replace(count(pdc.CNIC),'0','N/A') as TotalRegistrations,replace(count(s.studentid),'0','N/A') as TotalRegistered,
Replace(count(case when r.Grade is not null then 'Appeared' end),0,'N/A') as Appeared,
Replace(count(case when r.Grade='f' then 'fail' end),'0','N/A') as Failed,
Replace(count(case when r.grade <>'f' then 'pass' end),'0','N/A') as Passed

from PDC_PreRegistration pdc 
left join  Students s on pdc.Semester=s.CurSemester and s.nic=pdc.CNIC
left join studentresultnet r on s.studentid=r.studentid and s.CurSemester=r.Semester 
left join semester se on se.Semester=r.Semester
where pdc.semester 
in (select CurSemester from students where  batch='PD2110') 
group by pdc.Semester
ORDER BY  sem2,Sem1
```

The Result of the above query is as follows:

| Sem1 | sem2 | Semester | TotalRegistrations | TotalRegistered | Appeared | Failed | Passed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NSPP01 | 2110 | NSPP01 2110 | 2N/A | 2N/A | 19 | 2 | 17 |
| NSPP02 | 2110 | NSPP02 2110 | 37 | 35 | 24 | 1 | 23 |
| NSPP01 | 2111 | NSPP01 2111 | 76 | 42 | N/A | N/A | N/A |
| NSPP02 | 2111 | NSPP02 2111 | 121 | 81 | N/A | N/A | N/A |

I want to replace **'0'** with **N/A** but not 20 to 2N/A.

SQL Query without Replace function produces the following result.

```
select left(pdc.semester,6) as Sem1,RIGHT(pdc.semester,4) as sem2,pdc.semester as Semester,count(pdc.CNIC) as TotalRegistrations,count(s.studentid) as TotalRegistered,
count(case when r.Grade is not null then 'Appeared' end) as Appeared,
count(case when r.Grade='f' then 'fail' end) as Failed,
count(case when r.grade <>'f' then 'pass' end) as Passed

from PDC_PreRegistration pdc 
left join  Students s on pdc.Semester=s.CurSemester and s.nic=pdc.CNIC
left join studentresultnet r on s.studentid=r.studentid and s.CurSemester=r.Semester 
left join semester se on se.Semester=r.Semester
where pdc.semester 
in (select CurSemester from students where  batch='PD2110') 
group by pdc.Semester
ORDER BY  sem2,Sem1
```

Result of the above query

| Sem1 | sem2 | Semester | TotalRegistrations | TotalRegistered | Appeared | Failed | Passed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NSPP01 | 2110 | NSPP01 2110 | 20 | 20 | 19 | 2 | 17 |
| NSPP02 | 2110 | NSPP02 2110 | 37 | 35 | 24 | 1 | 23 |
| NSPP01 | 2111 | NSPP01 2111 | 76 | 42 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| NSPP02 | 2111 | NSPP02 2111 | 121 | 81 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: This is something for your presentation layer, *not* the RDBMS. `COUNT` returns an `int` and `'N/A'` is not a valid `int` value. Return `0` or `NULL` to your presentation layer, and it can then display `'N/A'` in the application.

Comment: Lazy way to do it. 
```CASE WHEN count(case when r.Grade is not null then 'Appeared' end) = 0 THEN 'N/A' ELSE count(case when r.Grade is not null then 'Appeared' end) END```

Comment: Note, as well, if you chose to go down the route of returning `'N/A'` from your RDBMS that means you need to convert your `int` data to a `varchar`, and of course, that therefore comes with all the problems that storing numerical data in a string based data type comes with; such as `'2'` being **greater** than `'10'`.

Comment: A better option is to return `NULL` like this `NULLIF(count(case when r.Grade is not null then 'Appeared' end), 0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code to replace "single-digit zero" with N/A is by using **IsNULL(NULLIF())** functions together.

`IsNULL(NULLIF(CAST(count(s.studentid) AS char(20)),'0'), 'N/A')`

```
select left(pdc.semester,6) as Sem1,RIGHT(pdc.semester,4) as sem2,pdc.semester as Semester,IsNULL(NULLIF(CAST(count(s.studentid) AS char(20)),'0'), 'N/A') as TotalRegistrations,count(s.studentid) as TotalRegistered,
Replace(count(case when r.Grade is not null then 'Appeared' end),0,'N/A') as Appeared,
Replace(count(case when r.Grade='f' then 'fail' end),'0','N/A') as Failed,
Replace(count(case when r.grade <>'f' then 'pass' end),'0','N/A') as Passed

from PDC_PreRegistration pdc 
left join  Students s on pdc.Semester=s.CurSemester and s.nic=pdc.CNIC
left join studentresultnet r on s.studentid=r.studentid and s.CurSemester=r.Semester 
left join semester se on se.Semester=r.Semester
where pdc.semester 
in (select CurSemester from students where  batch='PD2110') 
group by pdc.Semester
ORDER BY  sem2,Sem1
```

**Explanation:**

1. select Count(studentid) --**Results in count of records in studentid coulmn name.which can be single digit "0" or "00"**
2. select CAST(0 as char(20)) --**Casting result from Count Function int to char and then matching result with char "0" in Next step.**

```
SELECT  CAST(count(s.studentid) AS char(20))
```

3. SELECT  NULLIF(CAST(count(s.studentid) AS char(20)),'0') --**NULLIF(expr1, expr2).Here expr1 will come from SQL COUNT function as char and expr2 is char "0" which is hardcoded.**
   More Explanation of **NULLIF** is as follows:

```
select NULLIF('abc','abc') --**Results Null because both expressions inside NullIF have same value.٭٭
```

```
select NULLIF('0','0') --**Result Null because both Expressions inside NullIF have same value.٭٭
```

```
select NUllIF('20','0') --** Results 20 becuase Expressions inside NullIF have not same value.٭٭
```

4. ---ISNULL (expression, replacement)--- if the expression is NULL then **ISNULL** function will replace with a replacement which is N/A in our case, or if the value is not null then it will retain the value.

```
select ISNULL(NULL,' Value is NULL so replace by This expression') --**Results in Replace Expression.٭٭
```

```
select ISNULL('Any value', 'if the value is null then replace by This expression') --**Results in Any value.٭٭
```